# can not scroll down but there is an overflowing iframe

Tags: html, css

There is an iframe and a lots of 
 in the page to scroll down i thought it might work but it did not. 
here is the page html+css
http://fll.tevitol.org
what should i do ??

Comment: Can you please post the code here?  It will keep the question from going stale if that page ever becomes inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute;` for #content

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
}
```

It fix you trouble

You way for positioning elements is wrong. You should build your page without resorting to `fixed` or `absolute` positioning if it is not necessary. You should will read about module grid too.